# how can I play a 3gp movie (not streaming) in a form with c#?

Tags: c#, movieclip, 3gp

I want to be able to play small 3gp clips (not streaming) on a form.
How can this be achieved?

Thanks

R

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add video player components (such as WMP) to your project, Check out the links below:

[Check this out (Code Project)](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/directx/directshowmediaplayer.aspx), might point you in the rite direction :-)

Or [Here (C-Sharp Corner)](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mgold/PlayingVideo11242005002218AM/PlayingVideo.aspx?ArticleID=3d1c3b81-1a12-48e7-ad5e-758f96525409)

Or [Here (MSDN, example for AVI using directx)](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winforms/thread/53d1071b-26d9-406a-877c-3b33eedf8a4c)

Comment: That was quick, the MSDN example seems pretty simple, but not too sure about it's compatibility with 3gp though